# Double M/S System recomendations

Tags: field-recording, surround-sound, double, ms

Hi i´m planning a field recording trip (Turkey). I´m looking also for renting a double M/S Setup for beeing as much flexible as i can. So what are your thoughts about a Neumann km140 /120 combination inside a Rycote Stereo Blimp ? I also can get a Schoeps setup, but idon´t know the exacrt mic typs. But it´s double in price.
Any experiences ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of taste really. My take on this is that Schoeps and Sennheiser are the staples in high-quality, well-engineered field mics. Sennheiser being generally more technically appealing (better specs) workhorse mic (never fails, gets the job done), but Schoeps for the Schoeps sound, which to me is the most well-balanced around, pretty much regardless of what's recorded. Also, as Rene mentions, the noise level may sometimes be a deciding factor (Sennheiser wins here). And yeah, some people use Neumanns, but I think Neumann is better at studio mics.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture surround sound ambience, I'd recommend to you to use 2 stereosets instead of a double MS. Because of it's setup, Double MS is not 'really' a surround setup, it's something between of it. If you want to get something wide, take 2 stereo sets: one in front, one in rear.

best

Guido

Comment: do you mean something like a IRT Cross ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping for a MKH 8030 to be available, that would make a very cute little double MS-setup with two 8040s, for a reasonable price! And all with weather resistant RF-technique... *sigh*

... and thinking aboit alternatives that are more wide-sounding: I've heard some good things about the Holophone. Although it is probably more noisy than MKH-mics, because the holophone uses DPA4060's I think (not sure about this):

http://www.holophone.com/products/overview2

And DPA have their own baffle-system mobile surround mic, maybe that's for rent as well somewhere near you:

http://www.dpamicrophones.com/en/products.aspx?c=Item&category=117&item=24312

Comment: Ah, You´re right they´re safe from humidity. Thanks. I totally forgot about it


Answer (score 0):

i've never run the neumann rig, but my schoeps rig is always fabulous.

The schoeps sound tracks transients very well, and is a little warmer (less bright) than a lot of other SDCs.  Its not clinical though, its got a touch of schoeps 'flavor' that is pretty appealing.  noise floor not bad but slightly higher than some other rigs.

I know the sennheiser MKH 30 rig is also great sounding.  more on the flat and clinical side, but super low noise floor and tracks transients at least as fast as the schoeps.

I suspect that in comparison the neumann would sound a little brighter than the other two rigs.

Comment: "I know the sennheiser 8030 rig is also great sounding."
Where did you listen to the 8030? Is it being prototyped/tested already? Very curious!

Comment: ah, mistyped.  meant to put MKH30.  my fault...

Comment: how i wished you did actually see the 8030 in real life! 

Answer (score 0):

Besides noise level; on experience based: Sennheisers and Neumanns are less sensitive to damp weather than Schoeps. If Schoeps are used, be ready to carry your not used capsules in the pocket of your pants, nice and warm, ready to be swapped when the current one fails you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. i also prefer a sennheiser setup for that travel. let´s see, if i can get a affordable one for rent ;)
In the future i´m looking forward to get a setup for my own. So i tend to use Sennheiser. I think this will be a lifetime safe setup for Sfx and fieldrecording stuff.